# updated python code for class project doesn't move to different rooms or pick up inventory?

Tags: python

Trying to complete a text based game for class project in python where user can movee through different rooms and collect objects from each room before encountering a villain in the final room to win the game. Had all of the movement from room to room set up and working initially but now after adding in more code to include items and update players inventory, now it just stays stuck on initial display and won't move rooms or anything. Have tried various different things and I think there may be a problem with my dictionaries but I am stuck.  Any suggestions?

Here is my code so far

```
def start_menu():
    # Display instructions to game
    print('Operation Kill Hitler')
    print('You must collect 6 items before entering Hitlers bunker, '
          'or you will be discovered and killed before taking out the Fuhrer!')
    print('Instructions')
    print('move commands: go south, go north, go east, go west')
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")


# moving between rooms


def move_to_rooms(current_room, move, rooms):
    return rooms[current_room].get(move, current_room)


# add item to inventory and remove from room

def get_item(current_room, move, rooms, inventory):
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']


# dictionary links a room to other rooms and items in rooms


def main():
    rooms = {
        'Guest Room': {'name': 'Guest Room', 'go west': 'Library'},
        'Library': {'name': 'Library', 'go east': 'Guest Room', 'go south': 'Main Hall', 'item': 'silencer'},
        'Main Hall': {'name': 'Main Hall', 'go west': 'Officers Quarters', 'go north': 'Library', 'go east':
            'Dining Hall', 'go south': 'Wine Cellar', 'item': 'bullets'},
        'Officers Quarters': {'name': 'Officers Quarters', 'go east': 'Main Hall', 'item': 'nazi uniform'},
        'Dining Hall': {'name': 'Dining Hall', 'go north': 'Kitchen', 'go west': 'Main Hall', 'item': 'pistol'},
        'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'go south': 'Dining Hall', 'item': 'smoke grenade'},
        'Wine Cellar': {'name': 'Wine Cellar', 'go north': 'Main Hall', 'go east': 'Bunker', 'item': 'glass of wine'},
        'Bunker': {'name': 'Bunker'}

    }
    start_menu()
    # list of current inventory
    inventory = []
    # starting room
    current_room = 'Guest Room'

    # Game Loop
    while True:
        # display current location and inventory
        print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_room))
        print(inventory)

        # show if there is an item in the room
        if current_room != 'Bunker' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            print('You see the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            print('------------------------------')

        # handle if the user enters a command to move to a new room
        move = input('What do you do?:\n').title().split()
        if len(move) >= 2 and move[1] in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = move_to_rooms(current_room, move[1], rooms)

        # handle if the user enters a command to get an item
        elif len(move) >= 2 and move[0] == 'Get' and ' '.join(move[1:]) == rooms[current_room].get('item'):
            print('You pick up the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            print('------------------------------')
            # get_item(current_room, move, rooms, inventory)
            continue
        # handle if the user enters an invalid command
        else:
            print('Invalid move, please try again')
            continue


main()
```

Comment: Did you keep backups of the different versions?  If not, learn to do that next time.  If you do have backups, you can compare the two, and possibly start with a copy of the working version and add the changes in one at a time to see which one broke the movement.  If not, you can try commenting out the additions one by one until it starts working again.  Next time also try testing after each set of changes so when you breaks it you have fewer changes to look through to find the new problem

Comment: Learning to debug yourself is a critical part of development.  If we just give you a fixed version you won't learn to fix things on your own.  If you just take the answer and submit it  in class the next assignment will be harder than it should be.

Comment: One problem is that when you accept the movement input, you're only checking for a capitalized form of the second word of the input, but the room has **both** words as the key, in lowercase.  i.e. you're checking for the key `"West"`, but the actual key is `"go west"`.

Comment: Also you should probably verify that the first command word is `"Go"` for processing movement commands, just as you check that the first word is `"Get"` for processing inventory commands.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now able to move to rooms and display items in each room but can't seem to get the get item function to update my inventory